# HTML: How to give image url as input in input field

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add image based on the input by the user.

The user will enter image url in the input field and I will show that image after user submits the form.

Here is the complete code -

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { AddRecipe } from '../actions/index';
import Modal from 'react-modal';

class AddRecipeButton extends Component {
 
 constructor() {
     super();
 
     this.state = {
        modalIsOpen: false,
        title: "",
        ingredients: [],
        url: ""
     };
 
     this.openModal = this.openModal.bind(this);
     this.afterOpenModal = this.afterOpenModal.bind(this);
     this.closeModal = this.closeModal.bind(this);
     this.onURLChange = this.onURLChange.bind(this);
     this.onAddButtonClick = this.onAddButtonClick.bind(this);
     this.onIngChange = this.onIngChange.bind(this);
     this.onTitleChange = this.onTitleChange.bind(this);
   }

 openModal() {
     this.setState({title: "",ingredients: "",url: "",modalIsOpen: true});
 }
  
 afterOpenModal() {
     // references are now sync'd and can be accessed.
     
 }
  
 closeModal() {
     this.setState({modalIsOpen: false});
 }

 onTitleChange(event){
  this.setState({title: event.target.value});
 }

 onIngChange(event){
  let x = event.target.value.split(",");
  this.setState({ingredients: x});
 }

 onURLChange(event){
  let y = String(event.target.value);
  this.setState({url: y});
 }

 onAddButtonClick(){
  this.props.AddRecipe({title: this.state.title,ingredients: this.state.ingredients,url: this.state.url});
  this.setState({modalIsOpen: false});
 }
 render() {
  return (
   <div>
   <button className="btn btn-large" onClick={this.openModal}>
    Add Recipe
   </button>
   <Modal
          isOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen}
          onAfterOpen={this.afterOpenModal}
          onRequestClose={this.closeModal}
          contentLabel="Example Modal"
          className={{
       base: 'myClass',
       afterOpen: 'myClass_after-open',
       beforeClose: 'myClass_before-close'
     }}
         >
      
          <div id="modal-header">Add Recipe <button onClick={this.closeModal} id="close-btn">&times;</button></div>
          <hr id="modal-hr"></hr>
          <div>
           <label>Recipe Title</label>
           <input value={this.state.title} type="text" id="modal-recipe-title" onChange={this.onTitleChange}></input>
           <label>Ingredients (Seperated by commas ,)</label>
           <input value={this.state.ingredients} type="text" id="modal-recipe-ingredients" onChange={this.onIngChange}></input>
           <label>Recipe Image url</label>
           <input value={this.state.url} type="text" id="modal-img-url" onChange={this.onURLChange}></input>
          </div>
          {console.log(this.state.title + " " + this.state.ingredients + " " + this.state.url)}
          <button onClick={ this.onAddButtonClick}>Add</button>
        </Modal>
        </div>
  )
 }
}


function mapStateToProps(state){
 return {
   recipeList: state.recipeList
  };
}

function mapDispactchToProps(dispatch){
 return bindActionCreators({ AddRecipe: AddRecipe},dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispactchToProps)(AddRecipeButton);
```

But I am getting its value as undefined if I console.log the value attribute of the corresponding input tag.

Initially url is set to empty string "" and I want to set it to the url given by the user

I've tried converting the value to String and input type="url" also but not getting success. How to achieve this ? Is this even possible ?

Comment: you should not bind the function in the render function, if you are using react, bind the function in the constructor

Comment: I've seen people doing that but don't know any reason why it is the best practice. Thanks Vikrant for it but it doesn't seems to solve the problem

Comment: because render function will execute each time a change is done, and every time it will call the bind method, which will return another "bound function" everytime , different form the previous bound function. so the reference will change. the new function will refer to the new instance of bound function

Comment: So, basically we are saving memory by doing this. Am I right ?

Comment: no, you need to refer to the bound function, if you get a new reference it will not refer to the original bound function

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much we can do without the code, but you should just take the url as a normal input, save it in the component's `state` and put it as a img's src.

In the handler do you use `event.target.value`? It is always a string.

Do you console.log `this.state` after using `this.setState`? Because if you did, you should have passed callback as a second argument with console.log because of async nature of the function.

I can't think of anything else without actually seeing the code.

Comment: Added complete container code. I've tried converting event.target.value to string also but ultimately I am getting this as undefined in console.log

Comment: `event.target.value` is always a string in your case. Code seems fine, dont really see a reason why wouldnt it work.

Comment: When I paste image url in the input box and hit add. It gives me an error that map function can't iterate over undefined values and when I see what is undefined it show that key image has undefined value assigned instead of string url

Comment: Ok, but if you do console.log(event.target.value), can you see the correct value or not?

Comment: it is a highlighted and underlined text. So, not a normal string

Comment: That is called a console formatting, what other strings do you know? Come on man.. There is only one type of string. A string.